# What is combinator and how to write them in java

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

I'm reading the book [Fp In Scala](http://manning.com/bjarnason/) and the author speaks about purely functional state.

For example, the author writes the pure random generator like this (pseudo - code) :

```
def newSeed = (this.seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL
def obj = new RandomG(newSeed)
def n = newSeed >>> 16
[n,obj]
```

Here the author returns the `value (n)` and the `state (obj)`.  From the returned `state` we can get the *constant* random for the given *seed*

And later the author says:

> Looking back at our implementations, we’ll notice a common pattern:
>   each of our functions has a type of the form RNG => (A, RNG) for some
>   type A. Functions of this type are called state actions or state
>   transitions because they transform RNG states from one to the next.
>   These state actions can be combined using combinators, which are
>   higher-order functions that we’ll define in this section.

And he defines:

```
type Rand[+A] = RNG => (A, RNG)
```

and the `combinators` like this:

```
def unit[A](a: A): Rand[A] = rng => (a, rng)
```

From this I have two questions:

1. How does `unit` works? I'm not getting the idea.
2. How one can write the same `unit` in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title of your question and the content of your question are completely unrelated.

Comment: Sorry edited the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unit` is just a way to "wrap up" an ordinary value `a: A` as a `Rand[A]`, i.e. a function `RNG => (A, RNG)`, by having it return the `RNG` unmodified. I wouldn't really call `unit` a "combinator" (I reserve that term for functions that operate on functions, like `map` or `traverse`, and the passage you quote seems to agree), but the term means different things to different people.

In Java we unfortunately don't have type aliases or tuples, so we'd have to define types explicitly:

```
public class RngAnd<A> {
  public final RNG rng;
  public final A a;
  public RngAnd(RNG rng, A a) {
    this.rng = rng;
    this.a = a;
  }
} 

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Rand<A> {
  RngAnd<A> apply(RNG rng);
}

public static <A> Rand<A> unit(A a) {
  return rng -> new RngAnd<A>(rng, a);
  //I think that syntax is right, I haven't used it. In Java 7 it would be:
  return new Rand<A>{
    public RngAnd<A> apply(Rng rng) {
      return new RngAnd<A>(rng, a);
    }
  };
}
```